# How do I programmatically play a button animation?

Tags: windows-runtime

How do I make it look like a button was pressed using C# code? If I can actually push the button (play the animation and activate the events associated with the button press) with code that would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing the animation is pretty easy, using the Visual State Manager:

```
private async void PretendToClickButton()
{
  VisualStateManager.GoToState(myButton, "Pressed", true);
  await Task.Delay(250);
  VisualStateManager.GoToState(myButton, "Normal", true);
}
```

You can play with the delay as you see fit.

Programmatically raising the event is not possible; you just have to call the handler method(s) directly (which assumes you the code that handles the event).

[Edit: You could subclass `Button` and provide your own mechanism for simulating the `Click` event, but that makes the XAML a wee bit trickier]

Comment: Thank you! In my case I am using a keyboard key to activate the button, so I added code for KeyDown and KeyUp so that the button only appears to be pushed when holding the key down. Is there a way I can use OnKeyDown so that my event only fires once? Or is there a better way to do that?